# huffmandict error The symbol and probability vector must have the same length

Tags: matlab, compression, jpeg

I'm implementing this code for JPEG compression, but I get the error

??? Error using ==> huffmandict at 97
The symbol and probability vector must have the same length

this is the code, please help:

```
function y = mat2huff(x)
y.size = uint32(size(x));
x = round(double(x));
x = unique(x)
xmin = min(x(:));
xmax = max(x(:));
pmin = double(int16(xmin));
pmin = uint16(pmin+32768);
y.min = pmin;
x = x(:)';

h = histc(x, xmin:xmax);
if max(h) > 65535
    h = 65535 * h / max(h);
end
[map , w] =  huffmandict(x,h);   
hx = map(x(:) - xmin + 1);           % Map image
hx = char(hx)';                      % Convert to char array
hx = hx(:)';
hx(hx == ' ') = [ ];                 % Remove blanks
ysize = ceil(length(hx) / 16);       % Compute encoded size
hx16 = repmat('0', 1, ysize * 16);   % Pre-allocate modulo-16 vector
hx16(1:length(hx)) = hx;             % Make hx modulo-16 in length
hx16 = reshape(hx16, 16, ysize);     % Reshape to 16-character words
hx16 = hx16' - '0';                  % Convert binary string to decimal
twos = pow2(15 : - 1 : 0);
y.code = uint16(sum(hx16 .* twos(ones(ysize ,1), :), 2))';
```

Comment: is `size(x)==size(h)`?

Comment: Use [MATLAB's debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-177) to walk through your code and check the size of your data.

Comment: this is the problom, they are not equal, how can I call the function if they are not equal !!

Comment: how do I get the sizes to be equal? what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that your `histc` call does count the amount of `x` values per *unique* `x` value call it as

```
h=histc(x,linspace(xmin,xmax,numel(unique(x(:))));
```

Else, if you rimage is binary and your only values are `0` and `255`, `histc` will return a `size(h)=256` size array with lots of zeroes, because `xmin:xmax` is `0:255=[0 1 2 3 ... 254 255]`

Comment: it worked, but now I'm getting the error :
??? Error using ==> huffmandict at 91
Probability of an input symbol cannot be greater than 1

Comment: Please, read the function documentation and understand the algorithm! You want the probability, so you need to normalize h! `h=h/sum(h)`.

Comment: u mean voting up? I need to have a reputation of 15 :/

Comment: @user3818372 No, no need of voting up of you dont want! But there is a "greenish" tick under the votes that "accepts the answer as valid". This is important so future lost huffman encoders can find a solution that is know to be working! (thats how stackoverflow works)